# Error assigning one int pointer to another, but not when working with arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This code works just fine:

```
int main() {
    int arr1[4] = {5,1,1,5};
    int* arr2 = arr1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
         printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this one is either not running or giving me an unexpected output:

```
int main() {
    int* arr1 = {5,1,1,5};
    int* arr2 = arr1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this?

(This one works too, where is the logic?)

```
int main() {
    int arr1[] = {5,1,1,5};
    int* arr2 = arr1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok fixing right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning data to array using curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803873/assigning-data-to-array-using-curly-brackets)

Comment: not really, he did wierd stuff i gave three cases, why does case 2 works and case 3 doesnt?
arent they the same?
and what is the problem with 1, array in nothing but a pointer

Comment: [lots of warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/fW7hvj1fz) associated with `int* arr1 = {5,1,1,5};`

Comment: well, wont be using that anytime soon than.
but why 1 doesnt work? the array is a pointer, and i want another pointer to point to it as well

Comment: Arrays are *not* pointers! That's a very important point to make. Arrays can *decay* to pointers to their first element though. For example if you have `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` then using `arr` can decay to `&arr[0]`. So if you do `int *p = arr;` then that's really the same as `int *p = &arr[0];`.

Comment: arrays and pointers are not the same thing. I'm surprised `int* arr1 = {5,1,1,5};` even compiles, since you're initializing it like an array, but it isn't one. Some mysteries of the comma operator must be at work. `int* arr1[] = {5,1,1,5};` would make marginally more sense, but that makes `arr1` an array of `int` _pointers_, meaning 5, 1, 1, 5 are interpreted as addresses. The only places I've seen addresses hardcoded/magic numbers are embedded systems. In "regular" cases, use the `&` operator or return from `malloc` and friends to get addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some ways in which you can switch between them, in C, pointers and arrays are not the same thing as one another. An array is a sequence of objects that are laid out one after the other. So, for example, you can have

```
int arr[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 };
```

and in memory this looks like

```
arr   [ 3 ][ 1 ][ 4 ][ 1 ][ 5 ]
```

When you write `int arr[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 };`, C interprets this to mean "I'd like you to make me a new array of integers (`int arr[]`). And in particular, I'd like that array to hold the values 3, 1, 4, 1, and 5."

A pointer is an object that stores a location in memory. This is different than an array - an array is a sequence of values, and a pointer just says where to look to find something. What makes this confusing is that an array *decays* to a pointer, meaning that an array can be converted into a pointer to its first element. So if you write

```
int arr[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 };
int* ptr  = arr;
```

then things look like this:

```
arr   [ 3 ][ 1 ][ 4 ][ 1 ][ 5 ]
        ^
        |
ptr ----+
```

Intuitively, you can think of the line `int* ptr = arr;` as meaning "please make `ptr` point to the first element of the array named `arr`."

However, array-to-pointer decay only works if you have an actual array object to work with. If you write

```
int* ptr = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 };
```

the C compiler does ***not*** interpret this to mean "make `ptr` point to an array containing 3, 1, 4, 1, and 5." Rather, it thinks you're saying

- Please initialize `ptr` to the number 3 (oops, 3 isn't a pointer, so now your pointer isn't pointing to an array at all and is instead looking randomly in memory),
- and, by the way, when you're initializing it, I'd also like you to initialize it with the numbers 1, 4, 1, and 5 (oops, we don't know what to do with those).

This will generate a lot of [compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/fW7hvj1fz) (thanks to @yano for putting this together), indicating that the C compiler is worried that what you're telling it to do isn't what you meant.

There's no deep, fundamental reason why C couldn't have been designed so that the line

```
int* ptr = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 };
```

would mean "make `ptr` point to an array of five elements," but that's just not how the language works.

The general rule of thumb here is

- you *can* initialize an array by setting it equal to a brace-enclosed list holding the values of the array,
- you *can* initialize a pointer to point to the first element of an array by assigning it an existing array, but
- you ***cannot*** initialize a pointer to point at a brace-enclosed list of values that you want interpreted as an array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand completly now, thank you both very much.

Comment: and as for matrix, 
why is: 

int matrix[2][2] = { {1,2},{1,2}};
int** matrix2 = matrix;
printf("%d",matrix2[0][0]);

does not work?
i updated in the question as well, from the explanation it should work,

Comment: @רועיסלע I would recommend posting that question separately on the site so that more people will be able to see it. The explanation as to why that doesn't work is a bit different than what's involved with this question.

Comment: copy that, i will do it